# What is the best way to dynamically show dropdownlists based on multiple cascading input

Tags: jquery

In my MVC application using a viewModel I have 4 dropdowns which are placed in div tags.They are as follows:

Site  (15 different sites)
Department  (Electronics, Facilities)
EquipmentGroup (Different list depending on Department)
WorkOrders (cascading from both Site and EquipmentGroup)

Site and Department are not cascading.
EquipmentGroup cascades from Department. So far so good.

WorkOrder cascades from a combination of Site and EquipmentGroup.  I don't have an issue with dynamically populating the dropdowns, what I am wondering is how should I go about hiding the WorkOrders dropdown until I have the results of the Site and EquipmentGroup.

Should I have one dropdownlist and change it's characteristics when the other three are populated or two separate div's which each have their own dropdownlist and make one or the other visible once selections are made?

Answer (score 0):

Layout is up to you but as far as managing the display can do something like:

```
var $controllingSelects=$('#siteSelectID,#equipmentSelectID').change(function(){
     /* create boolean to determine whether to hide/show department select*/
     var showDepartment= $controllingSelects.filter(function(){
              return this.value !='';
         }).length ==2;

       /*run your  code to populate if(showDepartment) is true */

      /* hide/show department select*/
      $('#departmentSelectID').toggle( showDepartment);
});
```